# Expo XDE not working behind proxy

Tags: react-native, expo

Expo XDE has no provision to configure proxy details and hence it does not let you login because proxy does not allow the login request to be processed.

[image: Error while logging in to Expo XDE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After struggling for a few days with this error, I was able to login successfully.  The reason for the error message was that proxy was blocking access to URL `https://exp.host/--/api/v2/auth/loginAsync?_sm_nck=1` and required manual intervention to allow it by opening the URL in browser and authorizing it to pass through the firewall by completing the captcha on an intermediate page redirected to by proxy. Dev Tools played a key role in helping to discover the URL. To open Dev Tools, use `View -> Toggle Dev Tools` or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.